# Trying to write a little calendar program that displays on my desktop

Tags: python, tkinter, calendar

Trying to write a little calendar program that displays on my desktop. Everything works, except the rows in the output are center-justified and not the nice calendar grid layout. I'm pretty sure it's something with the label.config function. I am stuck. Python 3.7 on Windows 10.

```
    import calendar as cd
    import tkinter as tk
    from datetime import date
    from datetime import datetime
    from tkinter import *

    root = Tk()

    root.tk_setPalette('#000000')
    label = tk.Label(text="", fg="Light Blue")
    label.place(x=1,y=1)

    now = date.today()
    year = now.year
    month = now.month
    c = cd.TextCalendar(cd.SUNDAY)
    data = c.formatmonth(year,month)
    label.config(text=data)

    root.lift()
    root.overrideredirect(1)
    root.geometry("+530+1")
    root.geometry("130x130")
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a monospaced font and also add `justify` to your label.

```
label = tk.Label(text="", fg="Light Blue",font="Courier",justify="left")
```

Comment: It displays the actual month that all the 3 minute YouTube videos show. Font is pre-formatted. Tried every justify parameter, too. The rows with only 1 or 2 dates in them just move left or right. Tried =center, too.

Comment: I'm not sure what 3 minute YouTube videos you are referring to. If you use the above code, it should show up properly formatted (as least on my Windows 7 Python 3.7)

Comment: I'm a little dense sometimes, more if you ask my wife. Specifying the font got me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY, found a way.

```
import calendar as cd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *

now = date.today()
year = now.year
month = now.month
c = cd.TextCalendar(cd.SUNDAY)
root = Tk()
data = Text(root, fg="Light Blue", font=("Consolas", 10), borderwidth=0)
data.pack()
x = c.formatmonth(year,month)
data.insert(END, x)

root.tk_setPalette('#000000')

label = tk.Label(text="")
label.place(x=1,y=1)

root.lift()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry("+500+8")
root.geometry("150x125")
root.mainloop()
```